# How to insert distance sensor in Kuka robot in webots software

Tags: sensors, webots, kuka-krl

I am trying to add a distance sensor to a kuka robot in webots software KUKA robot that has no field called children but I added the distance sensor in bodyslot field now the sensor is reading nan all the time

```
#include <webots/keyboard.h>
#include <webots/robot.h>


#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <webots/distance_sensor.h>

#define TIME_STEP 32






int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 wb_robot_init();
//////////////////////////////

WbDeviceTag ps[1];
char ps_names[1][3] = {"DS"};


  ps[0] = wb_robot_get_device(ps_names[0]);
  wb_distance_sensor_enable(ps[0], TIME_STEP);

////////////////////////////////
// read sensors outputs
double ps_values;

  ps_values = wb_distance_sensor_get_value(ps[0]);
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  while (true) {
    step();

    printf ("\n %f \n", ps_values);
    //while (ps_values > 80){
    base_forwards_increment();
    //}
    
   // base_backwards_increment();
   
    
  }

  wb_robot_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ufZt.png)
To find a way to add a distance sensor to kuka robot

Answer (score 0):

It is correct to add new devices to the `bodySlot` field.

But you are retrieving the distance sensor values just once before starting the main simulation loop when the sensor is not active yet.
Instead you should call the `wb_distance_sensor_get_value()` instruction just before the print instruction to get the current sensor measurement.

Here is the fixed code:

```
WbDeviceTag ps[1];
char ps_names[1][3] = {"DS"};


  ps[0] = wb_robot_get_device(ps_names[0]);
  wb_distance_sensor_enable(ps[0], TIME_STEP);

////////////////////////////////
// read sensors outputs
double ps_values;

  ps_values = wb_distance_sensor_get_value(ps[0]);
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  while (true) {
    step();

    ps_values = wb_distance_sensor_get_value(ps[0]); // READ SENSOR MEASUREMENT
    printf ("\n %f \n", ps_values);
    //while (ps_values > 80){
    base_forwards_increment();
    //}
    
   // base_backwards_increment();
   
    
  }

  wb_robot_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://www.cyberbotics.com/).*